# How to make PDF file save on server folder using jsPDF ReactJS,

Tags: reactjs, jspdf

I am working on a ReactJS project where I've generated pdf using jsPdf.

It is currently saving pdf on client's system. But, I want to make it save on the server folder and then preview after saving.

Actually, this reason came up because google chrome is not showing pdf when I am trying to open pdf url(base64) in new tab, in monzilla it was working fine. That is why I want to make it save on server and then preview it.

Thanks in advance.

**Here is my code:**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import FirstPage from './mainPage.jpg';
import SecondPage from './secondPage.jpg';
import OtherPage from './otherPage.jpg';
import Placeholder from './placeholder.jpg';

  var pdfConverter = require('jspdf');
  const image2base64 = require('image-to-base64');
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
      Name:"Jimmy Kaler",
      firstPage:'',
      secondPage:'',
      otherPage:'',
      placeholder:''
    }
  };
  firstPage = () =>{
    image2base64(FirstPage)
        .then(
            (response) => {
                this.setState({firstPage:response});
            }
        );
  }
  secondPage = () =>{
    image2base64(SecondPage)
        .then(
            (response) => {
                this.setState({secondPage:response});
            }
        );
  }
  otherPage = () => {
    image2base64(OtherPage)
        .then(
            (response) => {
                this.setState({otherPage:response})
            }
        )
  }

  placeholderImage = () => {
    image2base64(Placeholder)
        .then(
            (response) => {
                this.setState({placeholder:response})
            }
        )
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this.firstPage();
    this.secondPage();
    this.otherPage();
    this.placeholderImage();
  }


  printDocument = () => {
    const {firstPage,secondPage,otherPage,placeholder} = this.state;
              const doc = new pdfConverter('p','pt','a4');
            var fPage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+firstPage;
            var sPage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+secondPage;
            var oPage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+otherPage;
            var pImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+placeholder;
               doc.setFontSize(14);
               doc.setTextColor(40);
               doc.setFontStyle('normal');
               doc.addImage(fPage, 'JPEG', 5, 0, 590, 842);
               doc.addImage(pImage, 'JPEG', 60, 90, 210, 130);
               doc.setFontSize(14);
               doc.setFont("arial");
               doc.setFontType("normal");
               doc.text(40, 240, 'Production Name:');

               doc.setFontSize(12);
               doc.setFont("arial");
               doc.setFontType("normal");
               var pDescription = "Here will be our production Name.";
               var splitDesc = doc.splitTextToSize(pDescription, 260);
               doc.text(40, 260, splitDesc);

               doc.setFontSize(14);
               doc.setFont("arial");
               doc.setFontType("normal");
               doc.text(40, 370, 'Deadline: 10/11/2017');

               doc.setFontSize(14);
               doc.setFont("arial");
               doc.setFontType("normal");
               doc.text(40, 400, 'Category: My Category');

               doc.setFontSize(14);
               doc.setFont("arial");
               doc.setFontType("normal");
               doc.text(40, 430, 'Total Duration: 5:00');

               doc.setFontSize(14);
               doc.setFont("arial");
               doc.setFontType("normal");
               doc.text(40, 460, 'Objective:');

               doc.setFontSize(12);
               doc.setFont("arial");
               doc.setFontType("normal");
               var oDescription = "Here will be our Objective description. Here will be our Objective description.";
               var splitObj = doc.splitTextToSize(oDescription, 260);
               doc.text(40, 480, splitObj);

               doc.setFontSize(14);
               doc.setFont("arial");
               doc.setFontType("normal");
               doc.text(40, 530, 'Target Audience:');

               doc.setFontSize(12);
               doc.setFont("arial");
               doc.setFontType("normal");
               var tDescription = "Here will be our production description. Here will be our production description.";
               var splitTarg = doc.splitTextToSize(tDescription, 260);
               doc.text(40, 550, splitTarg);

                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(40, 600, 'Contributors:');

                doc.setFontSize(12);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                var cDescription = "Here will be our production description. Here will be our production description.";
                var splitCont = doc.splitTextToSize(cDescription, 260);
                doc.text(40, 620, splitCont);

                doc.setFontSize(10);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(40, 680, 'Production Pin: EPIN001');

                doc.setFontSize(10);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(40, 700, 'Storyboard Printed On: 10/12/2018');

                doc.setFontSize(10);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(40, 720, 'By: GSV');

                //////////// Seconnd Page////////////

                doc.addPage('a4','p');
                doc.addImage(sPage, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 595, 842);

                doc.setFontSize(20);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("bold");
                doc.text(250, 80, 'Storyboard');
                doc.addImage(pImage, 'JPEG', 70, 310, 256, 150);
                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("bold");
                doc.text(70, 265, '1. Intro');
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(270, 265, '5 sec');

                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(70, 285, 'Title of Scene');

                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(340, 120, 'Description');

                doc.setFontSize(12);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                var desc1 = "Here will be our production Name.Here will be our production Name.Here will be our production Name.";
                var splitDesc1 = doc.splitTextToSize(desc1, 220);
                doc.text(340, 140, splitDesc1);

                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("bold");
                doc.text(70, 480, '2. Title Card');
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(270, 480, 'Duration');

                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(70, 500, 'Title of Scene');

                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(340, 320, 'Description');

                doc.setFontSize(12);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                var desc2 = "Here will be our production Name.Here will be our production Name.Here will be our production Name.";
                var splitDesc2 = doc.splitTextToSize(desc2, 220);
                doc.text(340, 340, splitDesc2);

                doc.addImage(pImage, 'JPEG', 70, 530, 256, 150);
                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("bold");
                doc.text(70, 700, '3. Full Video');
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(270, 700, 'Duration');

                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(70, 720, 'Title of Scene');

                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(340, 540, 'Description');

                doc.setFontSize(12);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                var desc3 = "Here will be our production Name.Here will be our production Name.Here will be our production Name.";
                var splitDesc3 = doc.splitTextToSize(desc3, 220);
                doc.text(340, 560, splitDesc3);

                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(340, 640, 'Teleprometer');

                doc.setFontSize(12);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                var desc4 = "Here will be our production Name.Here will be our production Name.Here will be our production Name.";
                var splitDesc4 = doc.splitTextToSize(desc4, 220);
                doc.text(340, 660, splitDesc4);


                ////////////   Third Page /////////////////


                doc.addPage('a4','p');
                doc.addImage(oPage, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 595, 842);

                doc.addImage(pImage, 'JPEG', 70, 60, 256, 150);
                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("bold");
                doc.text(70, 230, '4. Split Screen');
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(270, 230, 'Duration');

                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(70, 250, 'Title of Scene');

                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(340, 70, 'Description');

                doc.setFontSize(12);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                var desc4 = "Here will be our production Name.Here will be our production Name.Here will be our production Name.";
                var splitDesc4 = doc.splitTextToSize(desc4, 220);
                doc.text(340, 90, splitDesc4);

                doc.addImage(pImage, 'JPEG', 70, 270, 256, 150);
                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("bold");
                doc.text(70, 440, '5. Outro');
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(270, 440, 'Duration');

                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(70, 460, 'Title of Scene');

                doc.setTextColor(100);
                doc.setFontSize(14);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                doc.text(340, 280, 'Description');

                doc.setFontSize(12);
                doc.setFont("arial");
                doc.setFontType("normal");
                var desc5 = "Here will be our production Name.Here will be our production Name.Here will be our production Name.";
                var splitDesc5 = doc.splitTextToSize(desc5, 220);
                doc.text(340, 300, splitDesc5);
                doc.save("GSV.pdf");
                //doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');

            }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="mb5 btn1">
          <button onClick={this.printDocument}> Print </button>
        </div>
        <div id="divToPrint" className="mt4" >
        <h1>¯\_(ツ)_/¯</h1>
        <h1>（ ^_^）o自自o（^_^ ）</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```